# Corrupted Pen Drive Become 8GB to 64 MB & Become RAW Type

Tags: less, size, usb-drive, raw

1. When I connect the pen drive, it prompts for formatting and displays a message saying "D:/ Drive naming is not done properly."
2. While attempting to format, Windows reports that it can't format the pen drive.
3. The Disk Management shows the 8GB pen drive as having only 64MB of space.
4. The pen drive is displayed as RAW type, and I'm unable to convert it to FAT format.
5. Following YouTube instructions, the *cmd command Clean* works, but when I write "CREATE PRIMARY PARTITION," a significant error occurs.

I tried attempt to Format

chkdsk /f D:

diskpart

list disk

select disk X

clean

create partition primary
From this Command errors coming